# USB Multi Cable

Tags: camera, sony

I noticed that most of the Sony Cameras I have been testing with the JSON API come with support for the Multi USB Connection.  I was interested in if Sony has published the communication spec for this port or if anyone has found a creative way for communicating with a Sony camera utilizing this port.

Answer (score 0):

The micro USB multiport on *SOME* models use LANC (e.g. CX540, CX760). Models which support power via USB (on the microUSB) have sacrificed LANC control (e.g. AX33)